# How to make a sliding animation in scrollview when the keyboard shows up

Tags: android, animation, keyboard, scrollview, slide

I have an activity where i have a scrollview, and there is and edittext. When i touch the edittext, the keyboard shows up, and the scrollview is resized to prevent the keyboard to hide some space on the scrollview. And the scrollview is just jumping to that place where the edittext is in the middle. And that is not so pretty, i want the scrollview to slide. Can you help me with this problem? 
Thanks